# Error : not all arguments converted during string formating

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input(""))
for i in range(n):
  a,b = input("").split()
  if a%b!=0:
    r = a%b
    x = b-r
    print(x)
  else:
    print("0")
```

The error is:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

How can I make `a` and `b` as integers? Can anyone help me out

Comment: `a` and `b` are strings... `a % b` is a string format operator trying to format `b` into `a`. If you meant for `a` and `b` to be numbers, then the answer is in the link above

Answer (score 1):

#### Reason

The error is because if you do `input.split()` then the result will be this `['3', '5']`(let's say the input was 3 5) and `a`, `b` are both strings.

If you do `%` with a string, you will get `'3' % '5'` and it's not what you expected. This means string formatting in Python and you get the error.

you will get the same error with this:

```
a = '3'
b = '5'
print(a % b) # this cause the error. you will not get 3 % 5
```

#### Solution

You could do `int()` every time where `a` and `b` appears, but It will be too hard.
Instead, try this:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    if a % b != 0:
        r = a % b
        x = b - r
        print(x)
    else:
        print("0")
```

You can use the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function in Python and by the way, if you don't have any prompt for the input, then just leave it blank - `input()`.